# Запрос на авторизацию при помощи PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Для подключения к базе через PDO создан класс Connection при регистрации все нормально работает и происходит запись в БД, при авторизации когда также использовал метод query выдает ошибку, что класс Connection не содержит такого метода. В официальной документации написано, что если запрос содержит переменные, то необходимо использовать prepare и execute, используя их получаю следующую ошибку:

array(2) { ["login"]=> string(10) "rrrrrrrrrr" ["password"]=> string(19) " rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" }
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare() in /var/www/www-root/data/www/xxx.tech/system/auth.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/www-root/data/www/xxx.tech/system/auth.php on line 28

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

var_dump($_POST);

require_once('Connection.php');


$login = trim($_POST["login"]);
$password = trim($_POST["password"]);


if(mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90 ) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина логина";
    exit();
}else if(mb_strlen($password) < 5 || mb_strlen($password) > 90 ) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина логина";
    exit();
}

$pdo = new Connection();



$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `User_data` WHERE `login` =? AND `password` = ?");
$result->execute(array($login,$password));

$user = $result ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if($user && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
    echo 'Авторизация прошла успешно';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("Такой пользователь не найден")</script>';
    exit();
}


//$sql->close();

exit();
```

Comment: коннекции нет значит по какой-то причине, т.е. pdo например null или false

Comment: Использую этот класс для соединения в другом файлике, там все успешно. Поэтому и не понимаю, почему в одном месте он срабатывает, в другом нет